# LOAD DATA INFILE fields terminated by

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, field

I have searched through this forum but I didn't find anything related to this particular problem I'm facing with. Namely, I have a text file which I want to transfer to MySQL db, I'm using PHP for scripting.

What I want to know is can I by any chance use multiple delimiters in the FIELDS TERMINATED BY parameter:

> LOAD DATA INFILE '$file'
>
> > INTO TABLE $my_table
> >
> > > FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
> > >
> > > > LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";

My text file looks like this:

> 11;111111;;1111111;;;;;;1111;;;;11111;;1111111111;111111111;;;111; .....

So, by only using **';'** as the delimiter I don't get the wanted results, e.g. in some db fields I am getting data like **;;1111;** - normally there should be only numbers.

Is there any way to make all the semicolons act as a delimiter?

Comment: Can you give the table schema?

Comment: Basically it's a standard table with an id field and all the others twenty something fields are named col1, col2 etc... (type VARCHAR). I can load the data into the table, but the delimiting is not proper, meaning the fields are terminated by only one **;**  character as stated in the MySQL query. The following is how one improper field record looks like: **14848.00;;;21529.00** instead of two fields with data 14848.00 and 21529.00. What's the best way to go about this using MySQL syntax? I reckon the PHP solution would be something like replacing ;;; with *;* and then overwrite the text file?

Answer (score 1):

Your input txt file is not in proper format.

You can find and replace ;; with ; in text editor and then try loading data again into table.

Repeat this find and replace process two times to convert all semicolons to one.

Comment: No, that's not it. I want the text file as it is. All I'm asking is can the MySQL syntax be modified on the third row ( **FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'** ) so it could count the multiple semicolons delimiters as one semicolon delimeter between the numbers.

> ***111111;;;;;;1111;;;11 to be read as 111111;1111;11***

Comment: @pero if you do that your field to value mapping will break.

Answer (score 0):

\N between the delimiters in the data file. This marks the field as null when sql loads it.